# Has there been a Wayne in the Court of Owls?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52

I haven't read Batman Inc., Dark Knight, Detective Comics, or Batman & Robin in the new 52, just his flagship title.

Whenever Bruce Wayne talks about the Court, there is an obvious history between them and his family. He assumes they were involved in his parents murder when he was a kid, Alan Wayne (who I assume helped build the Gotham skyline in the 30's) was a Talon's target, and William Cobb said "I love killing Waynes" implying that it's almost a Wayne family tradition of pissing off the Court.

But the dialogue makes this rivalry seem a lot more personal, so I wonder if there was a Wayne in the Court who betrayed them and started this generation spanning fight.

Answer (score 2):

I'm of the opinion that it's unclear, even after reading all the Gotham-related books. There are no Waynes currently involved with the court, nor is there direct evidence that there ever were. The closest thing to a connection I can think of is that most (or all?) or the Talon's hide-outs are in buildings built using money from the trust Alan Wayne had left for the city. It's also established that the Talons' hide-outs are typically an entire floor of any given building which is not included on the blueprints when the building is built, nor does any elevator or stairwell service these floors. Theories on how they get away with this so expertly is another thing.

Bruce's tone when referring to the court is partly, as you say, because he believes they had something to do with his parents' murder (a theory he later drops due to lack of evidence), and also because one of the court claims to be Thomas Wayne Jr (Bruce's brother), the latter of which I'm fairly sure was never totally cleared up, but Bruce chooses not to believe it.

Comment: I can add samples from the comics I refer upon request.